# Change the hash of a PE executable by changing the checksum header

Tags: c#, md5, checksum, sha256

I am writing a code that calculates the MD5/SHA256 of a program and later I want to be able to change it.

I wrote the code for calculating the MD5/SHA256, which is:

```
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", ""));
        }
    }
    using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(sha256.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", ""));
        }
    }
```

Next I want to be able to change the values of MD5/SHA256 for the specified file. I have searched and all I found was this class:

```
class FileUtils
{
    #region VARIABLES
    private const int OFFSET_CHECKSUM = 0x12;
    #endregion

    #region METHODS
    public static ushort GetCheckSum(string fileName)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Invalid fileName");
        return GetCheckSum(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
    }
    public static ushort GetCheckSum(byte[] fileData)
    {
        if (fileData.Length < OFFSET_CHECKSUM + 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid fileData");
        return BitConverter.ToUInt16(fileData, OFFSET_CHECKSUM);
    }
    public static void WriteCheckSum(string sourceFile, string destFile, ushort checkSum)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(sourceFile))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Invalid fileName");
        WriteCheckSum(File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile), destFile, checkSum);
    }
    public static void WriteCheckSum(byte[] data, string destFile, ushort checkSum)
    {
        byte[] checkSumData = BitConverter.GetBytes(checkSum);
        checkSumData.CopyTo(data, OFFSET_CHECKSUM);
        File.WriteAllBytes(destFile, data);
    }
    #endregion
    }
```

Which I don't really understand how it works and only changes the MD5. Is there an easier way to do this, for not so advanced users? If this class works for what I need, could someone explain to me how can I use it?

Edit: I am aware that the MD5 of the file can't be changed, my goal is not to change the MD5 of the actual file, I want to add some contents to the file which would change the MD5 and by doing that I want the file to remain unchanged in functionalities.

Comment: To change hash of the file, just change the file.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us *why* you want to do that? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @dandan78 I want to change the MD5/SHA256 of the a file, so it is not the same (duplicate).

Comment: You can only change the hash of a file by changing the contents of the file.

Comment: @user A duplicate hash virtually always means that two files are identical. A hash is just a number that is calculated based on the input you feed into the algorithm. To change the hash, change the input, i.e. the file. But what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @dandan78 I'm not trying to achieve anything, except change the MD5/SHA256 of a file. I am just learning C# and I want to learn how to do this.

Comment: @user5204184 People are trying to tell you that your requirement doesn't make sense. Hashes are often used to determine a) whether two pieces of data are identical or b) a piece of data has changed since the hash was last created. Offsetting a hash does not make sense. While b) would still be given, a) would not. So: *why* do you need this if it breaks things instead of helping?

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenDittmar. I do understand the basic usage of MD5. My goal is to create nonidentical and unique file from a specific file, without changing its contents or corrupting it.

Comment: @user5204184 That makes no sense. Maybe you should tell us what your real problem is instead of following a flawed approach in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have or want two copies of the same PE executable file. Now you want to change either or both of these files, so that when you calculate a hash of the file's contents, they are different.

If you change the checksum, chances are the executable won't run anymore. If you're OK with that, you can easily use the class that you showed. It seems to assume a checksum consists of two bytes and is offset at byte 0x12 in the executable. I can't verify right now that it is correct, but at a glance it **doesn't seem to be**.

Anyway you can create your unique checksum per file and set it:

```
FileUtils.WriteCheckSum(sourceFile, destFile1, 1);
FileUtils.WriteCheckSum(sourceFile, destFile2, 2);
```

Now the two files will bear different contents, so the hash of their contents will be different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have 1 file (PE executable), but I can make a copy of it if necessary to do this. I want to change the hash of it. I need the file to be able to run, as it used to be before, without any changes, so if possible change some contents of the file which won't affect the previous version's functionalities.

Comment: I want to try your code, but I have two errors. 1. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'byte[]'.` Do I have to make it `new byte[]`? And second, what is `FileUtils`? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah `new byte[]` and `FileUtils` is the class you show.

Comment: Okay, I figured out what `FileUtils` is, it's the class I posted. I think I got it right and it changed the MD5. What I used is this. `byte[] hash1 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 };` `FileUtils.WriteCheckSum(sourceFile, destFile1, BitConverter.ToUInt16(hash1, 0));`. It worked fine, but I feel like asking, did I do any mistakes? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: And one more question, can I change the hash multiple times with this code? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can. Each time you call it, it will write the checksum header.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to change the index though? In your example, you use 1 and 2, do I have to start from 3, 4 and so on if I want to edit it again?

Comment: That is not the index, that is the checksum. You can pass an `ushort`, or 0-65535, meaning that (excluding potential collisions) you can have 65536 different checksums for the same executable, leading to a different hash per checksum. Using the same checksum will yield the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just decide that you want your file to have a different hash because the hash is a direct result of the data stored in that file. Two identical files, in terms of what they contain, will always produce the same hash, regardless of what their names are.

Any changes to the *content* the file itself will result in an entirely different hash value.

Comment: I understand that. My goal is to change the file, but without changing the contents of it. So the file remains the same, but the MD5/SHA256 is changed.

Comment: @user ***why*** do you want that? You cannot do that and it makes no sense.

Comment: @CodeCaster So the files are not identical. I want them to be unique.

Comment: @user no, that makes no sense. If two files have the same content, they _are_ identical. A hash is something you compute on the contents of the file, not something that is saved with the file. Explain why you think you need this, perhaps there's a more sensible solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster I understand it doesn't make a lot of sense and that the files _are_ identical even after MD5 change, but it _will_ solve the problem I am having here.

Comment: @user explain your actual problem in your question. Perhaps there's a more sensible approach that will work. What you want is impossible. You _could_ add the filename to the values that you hash, for example.

Comment: @CodeCaster The class I found modifies the file, by changing the checksum-field of the PE file header (which is not filled in and therefore won't make any changes to the real file) and by doing that it changes the MD5.

Comment: @user _"by changing the checksum-field of the PE file header"_ - so you _are_ changing the file's contents... Please edit your question to include all relevant information.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, I have edited the post hopefully it's clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is computed by passing bytes(a file for example) and representing them uniquely in hexadecimal, You don't change the "MD5" of a file, the result MD5 will change as the file changes.